# Javascript - Different markers for different types

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, switch-statement

I'm working on customizing Google markers on a map. Upon searching for a single area, the results return a map with markers of restaurants, parks, and meetups. I'm trying to give different marker icons depending on the type of result. So I added a 'type' argument to the addMarker function (whatami) and depending on the case, should switch to the correct marker. However none of the markers are showing up.

maps.js:

```
function addMarker(latitude, longitude, title, whatami) {

  switch (whatami) {
      case 'park':
      righticon = "'/assets/parkmarker.png'";
      break;

      case 'rest':
      righticon = "'/assets/restaurantmarker.png'";
      break;

      case 'meetup':
      righticon = "'/assets/meetupmarker.png'";
      break;
    }

  var markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerLatlng,
    map: map,
    icon: righticon,
    title: title
  });
  markers.push(marker);
  latlng.push(markerLatlng);
};
```

createevent.js.erb:

```
<% @restaurants.each do |item| %>
    addMarker(<%= item.latitude %>,<%= item.longitude %>,'<%= item.name %>','rest');
 <% end %>
  <% @meetups.each do |item| %>
    addMarker(<%= item.latitude %>,<%= item.longitude %>,'<%= item.name %>','meetup');
 <% end %>
  <% @parks.each do |item| %>
    addMarker(<%= item.latitude %>,<%= item.longitude %>,'<%= item.name %>','park');
 <% end %>
```

If I remove the switch statement it works fine. Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

typo at "'/assets/parkmarker.png'". remove the double quotes.

Comment: check the urls for your images. you may be 404ing. is addMarker being called anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance I would say that you've unnecessarily doubled up on your quotes, also you haven't declared righticon as a variable within the function how about something like this:

```
function addMarker(latitude, longitude, title, whatami) {
    var markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var markerSettings = {
        position: markerLatlng,
        map: map,   
        title: title
    }
    //  this way we still use the default marker when there is none set
    switch (whatami) {
        case 'park':
        markerSettings.icon = '/assets/parkmarker.png';
        break;

        case 'rest':
        markerSettings.icon = '/assets/restaurantmarker.png';
        break;

        case 'meetup':
        markerSettings.icon = '/assets/meetupmarker.png';
        break;
  } 
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerSettings);
  markers.push(marker);
  latlng.push(markerLatlng);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Your code made my markers show up; however they are all the default markers provided by Google and not my custom markers. I wonder why that's not working... This is how I'm setting the arguments in my code. Is it correct? 

addMarker(<%= item.latitude %>,<%= item.longitude %>,'<%= item.name %>','rest');

Comment: I don't speak Ruby, but if the lat, long and title are getting set OK I can't see why the whatami string at the end woudn't be coming through. How about trying the absolute URL for your images?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. The problem was the markers were being called in 2 different places and I only added it to one file. After adding it to both it worked. Silly mistake.